# Adding a node/property to an Expression Tree

Tags: c#, expression-trees

This is the first time I've really dealt with Expression Trees, and I am a bit lost. I apologise if
this question just doesn't make any sense at all. Consider the following classes:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public bool Update { get; set;}
}

public class Bar {
    public Foo<bool> SomeBool { get; set; }
    public Foo<string> SomeString { get; set; }
}
```

So right now I have a helper method that looks like this:

```
public void Helper<T>(Expression<Func<Bar, Foo<T>>> baseExpression, Expression<Func<Bar, T>> valExpression, Expression<Func<Bar, bool>> updateExpression) 
{
    // Do some stuff with those expressions.
}
```

And then it gets invoked like this:

```
Helper(b=>b.SomeBool,b=>b.SomeBool.Value,b=>b.SomeBool.Update);
```

But I dislike building three almost exact same expressions, and having to explicitly pass
them into the Helper. What I would prefer is to something like this:

```
Helper(b=>b.SomeBool);
```

And then:

```
public void Helper<T>(Expression<Func<Bar, Foo<T>>> baseExpression) 
{
    // Do some stuff
    var valExpression = ???; // append `.Value` to baseExpression
    var updateExpression = ???; // append `.Update` to baseExpression
}
```

But I'm not really sure how to do that... Its boggling my mind, any shove in the
right direction would be wildly appriciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure; if you have `baseExpression`, then something like:

```
var valExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Bar, T>>(
    Expression.PropertyOrField(baseExpression.Body, "Value"),
    baseExpression.Parameters);
var updateExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Bar, bool>>(
    Expression.PropertyOrField(baseExpression.Body, "Update"),
    baseExpression.Parameters);
```