# How to add a sub property to an Expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

For example using this classes:

```
Public class InnerClass
{
    string Value {get;set;}
}

public class ObjectClass
{
    InnerClass Inner {get; set;}
}
```

And with a method like this:

```
public void SomeMethod<TObj, T>(Expression<Func<TObj, T>> exp) where T : InnerClass
{
    // ??
}
```

I need to add "Value" property to the exp.

Calling the method:

```
SomeMethod(x => x.Inner);
```

I need to add value to the expression:

```
x => x.Inner.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell it what types you're using, otherwise it won't know:

```
SomeMethod<ObjectClass, InnerClass>(k => k.Inner);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your method to

```
public void SomeMethod<TObject>(Expression<Func<TObject, object>> exp)
{
     .....
}
```

then you can access the property

```
SomeMethod<ObjectClass>(x => x.Inner.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end this work for me:

```
public void SomeMethod<TObj, T>(Expression<Func<TObj, T>> exp) where T : InnerClass
{
    var newExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<TObj, string>>(
        Expression.PropertyOrField(exp.Body, "Value"),
        exp.Parameters);

    // now I can use newExp
}
```

From here: [Adding a node/property to an Expression Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794433/adding-a-node-property-to-an-expression-tree)